# TFS2018 web edit Build Definition Template

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS2018 and I have saved a build definition template. Is there a way to edit the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly using the website.
You could do 2 things:

a) Create new Build from the existing template, edit and save as Template.
This can be done with the website.

b) Use the rest-api to update your template: [Create or update a build definition template - visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definition-templates#create-or-update-a-build-definition-template)

Comment: Hi @D.J. thanks. I think I will go for option a but I think it would make more sense that it would be possible to edit the template. This is a common scenario.